# How to use XSLT to show the exact value from XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my first time using XSLT and XML.
So what I am asking is, how do I show only a particular product that has the same product_type such as 'mother board', 'fan', etc. ?
Maybe something like `product_type == "fan"`, I am not sure in this.
My plan is to create a different XSLT for each product_type.

Currently, I can only show every product from the XML.
The XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <products>
      <product>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <product_name>Test</product_name>
        <product_price>123</product_price>
        <product_type>MOTHER BOARD</product_type>
        <product_description>123123</product_description>
        <product_image>gpu_white.png</product_image>
      </product>
      <product>
        <Id>14</Id>
        <product_name>wwww</product_name>
        <product_price>1321</product_price>
        <product_type>FAN</product_type>
        <product_description>qwewqeqw</product_description>
        <product_image>hd_white.png</product_image>
      </product>
    <product>
        <Id>22</Id>
        <product_name>321123</product_name>
        <product_price>321</product_price>
        <product_type>MEMORY</product_type>
        <product_description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</product_description>
        <product_image>fan_white.png</product_image>
      </product>
    </products>
```

And the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
        <div class="main">
          <xsl:for-each select="products/product">
            <div class="box">
              <h3 style="color:white">
                <xsl:value-of select="product_name"/>
              </h3>
              <xsl:element name="img">
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                  product_image/<xsl:value-of select="product_image"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="width">
                  100px
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="height">
                  100px
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:element>
              <p style="color:white">
                RM  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(product_price,'0.00')" />
              </p>
              <p style="font-size:9pt;">
                <xsl:value-of select="product_description"/>
              </p>
              <xsl:element name="button">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">btn btn-danger my-cart-btn</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-id">
                  <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-name">
                  <xsl:value-of select="product_name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-summary">
                  <xsl:value-of select="product_description"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-price">
                  <xsl:value-of select="product_price"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-quantity">1</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="data-image">
                  product_image/<xsl:value-of select="product_image"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                Add to Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </xsl:element>

            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please add the expected output for a given `product_type` value?

Comment: @Filburt for example, I want to show only products with "fan" as their product_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple to do this. Just add your condition to the select expression in square brackets, to represent a condition

```
<xsl:for-each select="products/product[product_type = 'FAN']">
```

(Bear in mind it is case-sensitive)

Better still, use a parameter, rather than having a separate stylesheet per product type...

```
<xsl:param name="prodType" select="'FAN'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<div class="main">
  <xsl:for-each select="products/product[product_type = $prodType]">
```

How you pass the parameter to the XSLT depends on what XSLT processor you are using and what platform you are using to invoke it.

Note that you can simplify your XSLT a lot by removing the `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` tags, and just writing out elements and attributes directly, making use of Attribute Value Templates where you want the value of the attribute to be based on the value of an expression.

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="prodType" select="'FAN'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="main">
      <xsl:for-each select="products/product[product_type = $prodType]">
        <div class="box">
          <h3 style="color:white">
            <xsl:value-of select="product_name"/>
          </h3>
          <img src="product_image/{product_image}" width="100px" height="100px"></img>
          <p style="color:white">
            RM  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(product_price,'0.00')" />
          </p>
          <p style="font-size:9pt;">
            <xsl:value-of select="product_description"/>
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" 
                  data-id="{Id}" 
                  data-name="{product_name}" 
                  data-summary="{product_description}"
                  data-price="{product_price}"
                  data-quantity="1"
                  data-image="product_image/{product_image}">
            Add to Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The curly braces in the attributes indicate the Attribute Value Templates, and represent an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

Comment: I just realised I had missed out some curly braces in some attributes, so I have added them in.

Comment: Thanks it is working and your XSLT looks much better! btw I'd like to know more about how to pass the parameter as it is sounds easier than to create a separate XSLT file. I am using Visual Studio - C# to run this

Comment: Assuming you are using XSLCompiledTransform, this page has an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163439(v=vs.110).aspx